# Encoding utf-8 permite acentos?

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Se fizermos

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

na primeira linha de um programa Python, conseguimos fazer acentos no código todo?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Na realidade, tudo depende da configuração do seu editor de texto. A *maioria* dos editores de texto salva, por padrão, os arquivos na codificação UTF-8 (e, pelo menos para os lusófonos, os editores que não o fazem salvam em ISO-8859-1).

## Por que isso importa?

Pra resumir uma história bem complicada, que começou lá na época dos primeiros telégrafos, os códigos de caracteres do alfabeto latino foram padronizados bastante cedo (o [ASCII](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) foi padronizado em 1960), mas os caracteres “especiais” — cedilhas, acentos — foram “padronizados” por cada país (ou grupo de países) separadamente. A Europa Ocidental (e, portanto, países lusófonos, hispanófonos, …) convergiram no padrão [ISO 8859-1](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1).

O problema é que esse padrão não contém caracteres dos alfabetos grego, cirílico, …, então é impossível ter um documento neste padrão que, por exemplo, misture trechos de português com grego (e a situação fica pior ainda quando você inclui japonês, chinês, …)

## A invenção do Unicode

Para unificar essas codificações e permitir textos polílingues (e evitar ambiguidades na hora de trocar textos entre computadores com codificações diferentes), foi inventado o Unicode, cujo objetivo é atribuir códigos distintos a todos os caracteres de todas as línguas do mundo.

Textos Unicode podem ser codificados de várias formas diferentes — internamente, .NET e Java usam UTF-16; Python 3 escolhe entre ASCII, UTF-16 e UTF-32 dependendo dos caracteres que estão no texto que você está processando.

Ainda assim, UTF-8 é a codificação mais popular para arquivos texto (e.g. arquivos-fonte Python)

## Por que essa linha é necessária

Dado que um byte só pode ter 256 valores distintos, e o conjunto de todas as línguas do mundo tem mais de 256 caracteres, o UTF-8 precisa usar mais de um byte para representar alguns caracteres. Em geral, caracteres acentuados como na palavra “bênção” são representados em 2 bytes em UTF-8 (ao contrário de só 1 em ISO 8859-1):

```
             b |    ê   |  n |    ç   |    ã   |  o
ISO 8859-1: 62 |   EA   | 6E |   E7   |   E3   | 6F
     UTF-8: 62 | C3  AA | 6E | C3  A7 | C3  A3 | 6F
```

Isso é um problema quando você tenta ler um texto escrito em uma codificação como se fosse outra codificação: se o texto foi escrito como UTF-8 mas lido como ISO 8859-1, ele aparece como “bÃªnÃ§Ã£o”; o contrário aparece como “b�n��o” (ou, no caso do Python, causa um `UnicodeDecodeError`).

O Python 2, como um caso especial, detecta a presença dessa linha e a usa para detectar o encoding do arquivo. Na *ausência* dessa linha, o Python entra num modo mais conservador, e só aceita caracteres ASCII (sem acento), lançando um erro se ele encontrar algum caractere “esquisito” (os detalhes desse mecanismo estão descritos na [PEP 0263](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), que propôs a mudança).

## Resumo da ópera

Se você quiser usar acentos no seu arquivo Python 2, coloque uma das três linhas a seguir no topo dos seus arquivos:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# encoding: iso-8859-1
# encoding: win-1252
```

Em ordem aproximadamente decrescente de probabilidade, esses são os encodings que o seu editor provavelmente usa.

Você também pode migrar para Python 3, onde o código abaixo é perfeitamente legal…

```
fmoreira@saucer tmp $ cat encoding.py 
π = 3.14159265359
半径 = 2.5
área = π * 半径 ** 2
print('مساحة = {}'.format(área))

fmoreira@saucer tmp $ python3 encoding.py 
مساحة = 19.6349540849375
```

…mas eu obviamente não recomendo essa técnica.

Comment: Excelente resposta, parabéns.

Comment: essa resposta está bem legal - mas pulou alguns assuntos essenciais para a questão: em particular muita getne acha que colocar a declaração de "encoding" no começo do arquivo é uma mágica que vai fazer todos os problemas de codificação do programa sumirem.

Comment: Para ver com mais detalhes a história do Unicode e entender o que é, é imortante ler esse artigo. (o título não é pra tirar onda - ele trata do _mínimo_ que se tem que saber para qualquer programa que use acentuação). http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29

Comment: sobre a resposta -tenho uma ressalva: longe de tentar usar outras codificações até achar uma "compatível com seu editor" como está sugerido na última parte da resposta, é importante _sim_ usar utf-8 e configurar seu editor pra usar utf-8 (e não o contrário)-  utf-8 permite caractéres especiais de várias linguas no mesmo arquivo, é o padrão no Mac Os e no Linux (e portanto em quase todos os servidores onde sua aplicação web vai estar e no Android) - só não é o padrão no Windows.

Comment: Eu cogitei colocar isso na resposta, mas eu tentei minimizar o escopo — um programa que só contém caracteres ASCII pode engasgar com Unicode por exemplo. A minha intenção é só lidar com o caso onde, por exemplo, você quer colocar um comentário em português num código que, sem comentários, seria ASCII puro.

Comment: Você sabe como fazer isso nos editores mais populares pra Windows? Eu mexo mais em Mac + Linux; por isso que eu me abstive de tocar no assunto. Se sim, cabe postar uma resposta em paralelo.

Comment: Acho que "configurar o editor" tem que ficar como lição de casa para uqme quer programar. :-)  Cada editor vai ter essa configuração em algum lugar razoavelemtne óbvio "editr->preferencias->editor->codifciação", ou "ferramentas->codificação"  -- na melhor das hipóterses poderia ser uma pergunta para o 'superuser.com' -- E coloqeui uma resposta aparalela abaixo falando um pouco sobre os conceitos de unicode que você não abordou ai, de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 11):

A linha de declaração de encoding

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

permite que o parser do Python possa entender os acentos no código fonte - ou seja, colocar qualquer caractere acentuado deixa de ser um "erro de sintaxe" em Python 2. Outras codificações, usadas por padrão no Windows, são mais limitadas que o utf-8, no sentido de permitirem apenas 256 caracteres distintos - então é importante colocar essa linha e configurar seu editor para usar utf-8.

**Mas** isso não é o suficiente para usar acentuação à vontade num programa de Python 2.x. Uma mudança grande que foi implementada no meio dos anos 2000, e que muita gente ainda não se deu conta, é que dados de TEXTO no Python 2 têm que ser do tipo "unicode", não do tipo "str". No Python3, o tipo "str" já tem uma representação interna em Unicode.

A maior diferença entre os dois é que para uma string de bytes (a str simples de Python2) um elemento da sequência corresponde a um byte. Quando se fala de texto (tipo unicode) um elemento da sequência corresponde sempre há um caractere.

Faça o seguinte experimento - (pode ser no terminal, se ele estiver configurado para utf-8):

```
>>> a = "maçã"
>>> for letra in a: print letra,
... 
m a � � � �
>>> a = u"maçã"
>>> for letra in a: print letra,
... 
m a ç ã
>>>
```

O que acontece é que a codificação padrão do Windows em português ("latin1") usa semrpe um byte por caractere, e então não se percebe isso - mas você vai ter um problema se tentar passar uma string acentuada para maiúsculas, mesmo com esse tipo de codificação. Por exemplo:

```
>>> a=  "maçã".upper()
>>> print a
MAçã
>>> a= u"maçã".upper()
>>> print a
MAÇÃ
>>>
```

A recomendação é entender bem o que é Unicode e o que são as codificações no artigo http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_%28Sem_Desculpas!%29
, usar sempre utf-8 nos programas, e - sempre usar a técnica que chamaos de "o sanduiche unicode":

Ao ler texto de alguma fonte externa do seu programa - seja um arquivo, entrada do usuário, banco de dados, sensor, ele vai estar em bytes, e com alguma codificação

- você decodifica esse texto para unicode (com o método "decode")
- trabalha com o texto no seu programa em Python
- codifica de volta no encoding usado pela saída de dados (terminal, arquivo, banco de dados, impressora, etc...) com o método "encode".

Python 3 e algumas das bibliotecas - mesmo as usadas em Python2, já fazem o passo de codificação/decodifciação de forma transparente para você. Mas mesmo assim é vital entender o que está acontecendo.