# Função para substituir carácter não funciona quando dados vem do mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string

Utilizo uma função para substituir caracteres com acentos ou caracteres especias, mas quando fui utilizar a mesma função com dados vindos do `MySQL` a função não esta substituindo os caracteres.

Supondo que a cidade seja `Foz do Iguaçu`, a função retornaria: `Foz do Iguacu`, Logo, o **ç** seria substituído por **c**.

Nas estrutura do banco MySQL a  cidade está:

> tipo = varchar(80)
>   Colação = latin1_general_ci

```
$cidade=removeAcentos($row['cli_cidade'])

function removeAcentos ($string){
    // REMOVENDO ACENTOS
    $tr = strtr($string,
        array (
          'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A', 'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A', 'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A',
          'Æ' => 'A', 'Ç' => 'C', 'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E', 'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E',
          'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I', 'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I', 'Ð' => 'D', 'Ñ' => 'N',
          'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O', 'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O', 'Ö' => 'O', 'Ø' => 'O',
          'Ù' => 'U', 'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U', 'Ü' => 'U', 'Ý' => 'Y', 'Ŕ' => 'R',
          'Þ' => 's', 'ß' => 'B', 'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a', 'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a',
          'ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a', 'æ' => 'a', 'ç' => 'c', 'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e',
          'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e', 'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i', 'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i',
          'ð' => 'o', 'ñ' => 'n', 'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o', 'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o',
          'ö' => 'o', 'ø' => 'o', 'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u', 'û' => 'u', 'ý' => 'y',
          'þ' => 'b', 'ÿ' => 'y', 'ŕ' => 'r', 'º' => '', 'ª' => ''
        )
    );

    return $tr;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou `$cidade=removeAcentos(utf8_encode($row['cli_cidade']))`?

Comment: Não funcionou, tentei forçar também ((string) ($row['cli_cidade'])) mas também não deu certo. @KaduAmaral

Answer (score 1):

```
fmoreira@saucer UnmergedCode $ echo '<?= strlen("Á") ?>' | php
2
```

O problema é que [caracteres acentuados em UTF-8 ocupam dois (ou mais!) caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67604/encoding-utf-8-permite-acentos/67610#67610); `strtr` opera sobre bytes, não sobre caracteres.

Você pode usar [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) (apesar de que você vai ter que separar o seu vetor em dois), ou se você conseguir instalar a extensão `intl` do PHP (você vai precisar mexer no `php.ini` e ligar a `php_intl.dll`; eu tentei aqui no meu Mac mas não consegui), você pode usar a [`normalizer_normalize`](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php).

Internamente, uma chamada a `normalizer_normalize('bênção', Normalizer::FORM_D)`  converte uma string tipo `bênção` em algo tipo `be^nc¸a~o`, quebrando as letras “acentuadas” na letra original nos respectivos penduricalhos. Daí você pode usar uma expressão regular tipo `[^a-zA-Z]` pra detonar tudo que NÃO é letra.

(Você ainda vai precisar fazer `str_replace` pra “letras” tipo ‘ª’.)

---

Eu reparei que você está substituindo ‘þ’ por ‘b’, mas a [melhor transcrição fonética](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letra)), apesar da similaridade visual, é ‘th’. Se você espera ter que processar esses caracteres esquisitos, eu acho mais robusto você usar alguma variante da [unidecode](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-unidecode), uma biblioteca que também converte, e.g. “北亰” em “Bei Jing”.