# Programa fechando imediatamente após abrir(Pós compilado)

Tags: python, compilação, tkinter

Estou começando a estudar Tkinter e compilação, e tenho uma noção básica de Python, e estou tendo alguns problemas. Aí vai um exemplo de programa básico que, após compilar, o executável apenas abre rapidamente um cmd e fecha, sem mais nenhum tipo de resposta, já tentei usar while True antes do código, mas não surtiu efeito.Deve ser algo bem besta, mas é uma dúvida legítima.

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
#####################################
abc='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
rot=3
def cifrar(message):
    m=''
    n=0
    for c in message:
        c_index = abc.index(c)
        if c_index<23:
            m+=abc[c_index+rot]
        elif c_index==23:
            m+='a'
        elif c_index==24:
            m+='b'
        elif c_index==25:
            m+='c'
        else:
            m+=c
    return m
def decifrar(message):
    m=''
    for d in message:
        d_index=abc.index(d)
        if d_index>=3:
            m+=abc[d_index-rot]
        elif d_index==0:
            m+='x'
        elif d_index==1:
            m+='y'
        elif d_index==2:
            m+='z'
        else:
            m+=d_index
    return m
#####################################
janela=tk.Tk()
janela.title('Convertor da Cifra de César')
def bt_click():
    lb2['text']=str(cifrar(ed.get()))
janela['bg']='red'
########
cores=['blue','green','red','black']
######
def bt_click2():
    lb2['text']=str(decifrar(ed.get()))
#
def changec():
    janela['bg']=str(cores[random.randint(0,3)])
#
ed=Entry(janela, width='47')
ed.place(x=50,y=150)
#
lb=Label(janela, text='Convertor da Cifra de César')
lb.place(x=50,y=40)
lb.config(font=('Comic_Sans', 14))
#
lb2=Label(janela,text='', width='40')
lb2.place(x=50,y=180)
#
bt=Button(janela,text='Cifrar',command=bt_click, width=15)
bt.place(x=50,y=250)
#
bt2=Button(janela,text='Decifrar', width='15',command=bt_click2)
bt2.place(x=180,y=250)
#
bt3=Button(janela,text='Mudar cor de fundo',command=changec)
bt3.place(x=285,y=281)
#
janela.geometry(('400x300+320+140'))


janela.mainloop()
```

Código do arquivo setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import cx_Freeze
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'

executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable('CeasarCypher.py')]

cx_Freeze.setup(name='CeasarCypher',version='0.1',description='foda',
      options={'build_exe':{'packages':['tkinter']}},
      executables=executables,
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Problema está aqui:

```
janela.title('Convertor da Cifra de César')
```

Você precisa colocar a codificação no inicio do código. Assim o python consegue reconhecer os caracteres unicode.

```
#encoding: utf-8
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
```

Ou execute com o python3, nao sera necessario colocar `#encoding: utf-8`

Caso queira saber mais sobre codificações: [Encoding utf-8 permite acentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67604/encoding-utf-8-permite-acentos)

Comment: Eu acabei de fazer isso, porém, depois de compilar de novo, continua na mesma situação. Acho que talvez haja algum erro no arquivo setup, mas não sei dizer.Só por desencargo de consciência, vou deixar código de setup na pergunta.