# Erro na acentuação no Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Durante a codificação(abaixo) esta aparecendo erro quanto a acentuação de algumas palavras:

Observação:estou usando o notepad++ e executo o python 2.7 no cmd do windows

**Codigo:**

```
# encoding: utf-8
import os, sys

print "EXPEDIÇÃO DE DESPACHO"
```

**Saida:**

```
λ python teste1.py
EXPEDI├ç├âO DE DESPACHO
```

**Imagem**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Verifiquei esta pergunta em outra postagem porém não ajudou: [Encoding utf-8 permite acentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67604/encoding-utf-8-permite-acentos)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Encoding utf-8 permite acentos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67604/encoding-utf-8-permite-acentos)

Comment: Eu já tinha lido, porém não ajudou. Estou usando o windows e o notepad++

Comment: Acredito e estou usando a python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente em cmd com Python2.7 basta usar o `u"..."`, assim:

```
print u"á é í"
```

Note que o documento também deve ser salvo em **utf-8 sem BOM**

Usando **notepad++**:

[image: utf8 sem boom notepad++]

Usando **Sublime Text**:

[image: utf8 sublime sublimetext]

<s>Testei no `cmd.exe` nativo, mas não funcionou, irei editar a resposta assim que conseguir uma solução técnica e um detalhamento sobre o que muda do python2.7 e 3.x, pois o 3.x funciona corretamente sem precisar usar o comando `chcp`.</s>

No cmd não funcionou, mas no cmder funcionou usar o comando `chcp 65001` antes de executar o python, então pode fazer isso direto via script, exemplo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys

os.system('@chcp 65001')

print "EXPEDIÇÃO DE DESPACHO"
print "expedição de despacho"
```

Resultado:

[image: Acentos no cmder com python2.7]

Comment: Guilherme, a primeira resposta funcionou no cmder.  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys

os.system('@chcp 65001')

print "EXPEDIÇÃO DE DESPACHO"

Comment: Quanto a segunda versão não!

Comment: Não encontrei um explicação para esta fato. Estranho notar este tipo de comportamento no python 2.7

Comment: @alexjosesilva o uso do `u` funcionou tanto no cmd.exe quanto no cmder aqui assim `print u"á é í"`, usando Python2.7, fecha o cmd e o cmder e tenta novamente, lembre-se, tem que salvar o script como utf-8 também ;)